# Additional domain on existing DC

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

Is it possible to add a second domain to an existing Windows 2008 server? This server is already hosting a DC (dc1). I tried `dcpromo` and wizard prompted me that existing DC will be erased or inactivated if go through the process.

Comment: Do you want it to host an entire Active Directory domain, or just hold a zone for another DNS domain? Your terminology is jumbled and unclear, can you please edit your question to be more consise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have two separate AD domains on a single server, the answer is no - you can't do this. If you want two separate AD domains, you need (at a minimum) two servers.

If you want to add a second DNS zone to a Domain Controller running DNS, you can do this through the DNS manager > Add New Forward Lookup Zone.

Comment: Thanks. Okay, I will a bare minimum w2k8 server for the second domain. Thanks

Comment: In almost all cases, you will want 2 DCs per domain. If one is down, you're kind of dead in the water. If it matters to business productivity at all, you should have 2 DCs per domain, minimum.

Comment: Additionally, there aren't a ton of reasons to run a second domain. You may want to review your needs and the AD DS deployment guides to determine if you can do what you want with GPOs, or AD LDS, or other options besides deploying a whole second domain.

Comment: Yeah, @mfinni is definitely right. I answered your question from a technical perspective assuming that you have a legitimate need for a 2nd domain, but in almost all cases, it's unnecessary.